# Re-parse Zend_Dojo_Form coming in AJAX reply. is it possible?

Tags: ajax, forms, zend-framework, dojo, render

I have searched everywhere for an answer but could get any.

Simple issue, i'm getting a Zend_Dojo_Form in an AJAX call, but still haven't found a way to get Dojo to parse it again so it renders properly.

this is the AJAX reply:

```
<div id="formcontainer">
<form id="UserLoginInfo"><dl class="zend_form_dojo">
<dt id="userid-label">&#160;</dt>
<dd id="userid-element">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="" id="userid" /></dd>
<dt id="email-label"><label for="email" class="required">Endereço de Email</label></dt>
<dd>
<input id="email" name="email" value="" type="text" /></dd>
<dt id="role-label"><label for="role" class="required">Função</label></dt>
<dd>
<select name="role" id="role" trim="1" promptMessage="Função atribuída a este utilizador" onChange="checkCustomer(this)">
<option value="126" label="Administrador Local">Administrador Local</option>
<option value="94" label="Consultor Local">Consultor Local</option>
<option value="62" label="Operador Local">Operador Local</option>
<option value="1" label="Visitante">Visitante</option>
</select></dd>
<dt id="firstname-label"><label for="firstname" class="required">Nome</label></dt>
<dd>
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" type="text" /></dd>
<dt id="lastname-label"><label for="lastname" class="required">Apelido</label></dt>
<dd>
<input id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" type="text" /></dd>
<dt id="password-label"><label for="password" class="required">Password</label></dt>
<dd>
<input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" /></dd>
<dt id="passwordretype-label"><label for="passwordretype" class="required">Re-introduza Password</label></dt>
<dd>
<input id="passwordretype" name="passwordretype" value="" type="password" /></dd></dl>    </form>
</div>
```

Then I'm calling

```
dojo.parser.parse('formcontainer');
```

But it doesn't work!!

So my question is, can this be done at all? If so, how?

TIA

Comment: After searching a bit more i found out that the probably parser is not handling the elements because they have no "**data-dojo-type**" attribute set. Is there any way to force Zend_Dojo_Form to render that attribute also?

Answer (score 0):

if you use something like this, it should parse it automatically ...

```
dijit.byId("somedijitcontainerId").setContent("data-returned-from-ajax-call");
```

your "somedijitcontainerId" dijit type could be "dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane"